# Adding new HTML tags with JavaScript to a text block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After page is done loading, I would like script to add tags to certain parts of the text within it. For example:

```
    <p> Some text is here. The page has already finished loading</p>
```

to

```
    <p> Some text is <b class="bolded">here</b>. The page has already finished loading</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling a function onload of page.
  Give the ID to the elements of HTML and write the below code

HTML :

```
<p  id='testing1'> Some text is here. The page has already finished loading</p>
```

Javascript:

```
 function onLoad()
  {
     var strTest = $("#testing1").html();
strTest = strTest.replace("here",'<b class="bolded" style="font-weight:bold;">here</b>');
console.log('strTest:',strTest);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can do something like $("p")  or add an ID at your `<p>` example:

```
<p  id='testing1'> Some text is here. The page has already finished loading</p>
```

then when after the string render and you may use the script as below to replace it:

```
var strTest = $("#testing1").html();
strTest = strTest.replace("here",'<b class="bolded" style="font-weight:bold;">here</b>');
console.log('strTest:',strTest);
```